# after unzipping mongo dump, can't write it locally to database via mogorestore

Tags: mongodb, mongorestore

I downloaded from a remote server a database dump in bz2 format

Then I extracted it with the command: `bzip -d mongodump_name`

I'm trying to deploy this database locally: `mongorestore -db <path_to_folder_with_binary_dump_file>`

And I get an error: **don`t know what to do with file ....**

What am I doing wrong and should the versions of mongo on the local and on the remote server strictly match?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Was the dump created with `mongodump` or `mongoexport`?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I really don’t know, it wasn’t me who did the dump, but they already helped me, I don’t remember exactly the command line already, but there was archive= in front of the name of the dump itself, it seems, I’m not sure.

Comment: If you understand what I mean, you can format the answer with this line in full and I will accept it. The person told me that this is due to the fact that in addition to the fact that I unpacked the dump, Mongo itself also does it. Something like that...

Comment: In order to dump a Mongo database you can use `mongodump` or `mongoexport`, they create different export formats (none of them is "bz2"). Depending on the export you must restore either with `mongorestore` or `mongoimport`